# How does i get Axios post request is progressing

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, axios

It's a simple thing I want to achieve (Simple Ajax Request. I'm using **Axios** for that.)

It like when a user clicks on a button an ajax request is fired meanwhile the request is processing or until it's finished the request I want to disable the button *( or anything else something like user cannot interact with the interface or showing a progress bar to the user )*. please see the code comment you will understand what I really want to say.

In Axios get method works perfectly see the code below

```js
axios.get(url, {
        onDownloadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
            // for get method its working perfectly
            // ajax is processing
            // i can disable the button
        },
        onUploadProgress: function (evt) {
            // this event method never fired
        }
    }).then(res => {
       // ajax is finished
       // i can enable the button again
    })
```

But in post method it doesn't work - now what can I do for that

```js
axios.post(url, {
        onDownloadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
            // this event method never fired
        },
        onUploadProgress: function (evt) {
            // this event method never fired
        }
    }).then(res => {
       // ajax is finished
       // i can enable the button again
    })
```

Without Axios its work perfectly

```js
    let xml = new XMLHttpRequest();

    let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="_token"]').getAttribute('content');

    xml.open("POST", "/test");
    xml.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", token);


    xml.addEventListener('progress', function(evt) {
            // ajax is processing
            // i can disable the button
    });

    xml.addEventListener("load", function(evt){
        // ajax is finished
       // i can enable the button again
    });
    xml.send();
```

***Note: I am using laravel framework***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the post method from axios the following way:

```
axios.post(path, data, options)
```

In your case you are passing options object instead of data object for POST request. Solution would be to pass empty object as data, if you don't want to send anything with you request:

```
axios
  .post(
    url,
    {},
    {
      onDownloadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
        // ...
      },
      onUploadProgress: function(evt) {
        // ...
      }
    }
  )
  .then(res => {
    // ...
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example with axios making post request. 
The function **onUploadProgress** fires whenever you pass data in body...

```
axios({
  url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    username: 'Hello',
    password: 'World'
  },
  onDownloadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
    console.log("___ Document loading ____");
  },
  onUploadProgress: function(evt) {
    console.log('This is the event', evt); // Need to stream
  }
}).then(res => {
  console.log("___ Document loaded ___");
  console.log(res);
});
```

Here you can find my example on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-elgamal-n096d)